# Xss in jsp using href, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jsp, xss, encode, veracode

Veracode scan detect issue( [CWE ID 80](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/80.html)) in my jsp here:

```
 <a href="javascript:constructURL('${id}','${type}');">
```

**where**

```
function constructURL(id, type) {
            var queryString = new ConstructQString('controller.do');
            queryString.add('id', id);
            queryString.add('sampleType', type);
            windowOpener.createWindow(queryString.getUrl(), 'url', false, position);
        }
```

What is the problem here? I need to escape URL? I can not see how the attacker can change the URL if it changes the id for example the response will be 403. What Veracode what to say here and how to prevent future XSS attack?

Note:
ConstructQString encode the passed paramters.

Comment: what is the output of your `queryString.getUrl()` ?

Comment: concatenate baseURL + queryString. Here I am wondering if Veracode make clever assumption or just decide that when we construct URL in js it is dangerous.

Comment: Generally for XSS, we tag any case where input from a user or that can be manipulated by a user (including things like form inputs, query strings, cookie values, etc.) is used to form a string that is displayed to the user, without some sort of well-recognized sanitizing function. In this case we're flagging in the JSP where you are passing two parameters, ID and type. You don't show a stack trace but if either is user provided there could be a problem.

If you have questions, feel free to contact Veracode support for a quick discussion about where and how to sanitize the values here.

Comment: @TimJarrett the value come from db. I will esacep it and run the test. I noticed that for Veracode there is very little toppics here in stackoverflow, so please do more deep explanations thill theVeracode comunity sustain itself.
Here please as answer give possible variations as the post above. Veracode checks that and that you have to be sure that this and this is escaped... And one more is there esapi.tld destributed with Veracode?

Comment: Hi Xelian, agree that more information could be provided and we're looking at better ways to engage with StackOverflow. I'm unfortunately not one of our security consultants so can't provide the additional detail you're looking for.

Comment: I put escapeJavaScript around type, so Veracode wants everything to be escaped and protected against js attacks.

Comment: Any luck with a fix for this? I have a similar issue.